# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.BreakpointSupport

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I am updating Apache Camel project to the latest version. The whole project compiles fine but when I run tests I see the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/impl/BreakpointSupport

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.<init>(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:23)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.<init>(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.util.RunnerProvider.newInstance(RunnerProvider.java:39)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.RunnerFactory.create(RunnerFactory.java:28)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.<init>(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.BreakpointSupport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more
```

I don't understand why the project compiles but when I run tests it's failing. The unit tests doesn't even run.

**Update** (here are my maven camel dependencies):

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-netty4-http</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cache</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stax</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>spi-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- XSL conversion -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-saxon</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

where `camel.version` is `3.0.0-M4`

Comment: Could you add the maven dependencies you have for Apache Camel in your pom.xml ?

Comment: before seeing your pom/build file this is most likely a dependency mismatch, you have a conflict between some of your dependencies

Comment: Strange, I just downloaded the 3.0.0-M4 jar from maven repo (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core/3.0.0-M4), and indeed this class isn't present. It is in the 3.0.0-M2 though .

Comment: @Arnaud Updated with camel pom versions. I thought it was a conflict between some of my dependencies but having looked through the dependency tree and the test its just not obvious where the miss-match is.

Comment: @Arnaud I've updated it to `3.0.0-M2` and it introduces even more of similar issues but regarding different classes. e.g. ```javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.camel.util.jndi.CamelInitialContextFactory
 [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.util.jndi.CamelInitialContextFactory]``` and ```java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.util.StopWatch.stop()J```

Comment: There is no such class in 3.0.0.0-M4 https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/3.0.0-M4/org/apache/camel/impl/package-tree.html

Comment: You have mixed Camel versions in the pom.xml - do NOT do that, use the same Camel version. And there is a RC1 which is a newer version. Also mind its Camel 3 which is still in development, but expected to be GA end of this year.

Answer (score 0):

I found that BreakpointSupport in 3.0.0-M4 was moved to other location `org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor` in camel-base module.

You have to add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-base</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```